In no display environment,i.e. pure text terminal,ffplay can't capture the keypressing event on debian 12
debian 12
ffmpeg version 5.1.6-0+deb12u1
In the pure text terminal(without X or wayland),I can use the ffplay to play the video.(maybe ffplay use some sdl),but I can't quit the ffplay by ESC or q or ctrl-q or ctrl-c meanwhile the video plays well.Actually no key has responded, space,arrow,ctrl-alt-F2... none of them worked.
In X,I can quit the ffplay by ESC ...,but in the pure text terminal It doesn't work.
I want to know if anyone has the same issue,is it a feature,and why?
